# how to set the table prefix in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I need to add a table prefix to zend framework configurations. But it seems really complicated matter adding such a configuration (I have to add too many lines of code to do that). Is there a way to set the table prefix in a simple manner? (like other frameworks do). I'm using Zend Framework 1.11

Comment: that depends on how you have it set up now - what do your table classes look like? Are you using concrete table classes or dynamically configured tables Zend_Db_Table instances?

Answer (score 2):

if you use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, you could extend this class like this:

```
class My_Db_Table_Abstract extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
     protected function _setupTableName()
     {
         parent::_setupTableName();
         $prefix = 'StackOverflow'; // maybe from config..
         $this->_name = $prefix . '_' . $this->_name;
     }
}

class User extends My_Db_Table_Abstract
{
        $this->_name = 'user';
}
```